# Cannot GET http requests for Rest api in angular 2

Tags: json, angular, magento2

Im trying to get http GET requests in angular 2 frontend using the Rest api created in magento 2.

**\var\www\html\Angular2\sample-ng-http-master\web\app\app.component.ts**

```
///<reference path="../node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts" />
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
import {Component, Input} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';

interface Person {
    //name: string;
    //age: number;
 }

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>
    <div>{{people | json}}</div>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
    @Input() private people: Person[];

    constructor(private http: Http) {
    }

 public ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get('http://10.20.1.2:3000/data.json')
        .map(response => {
            console.log(response.json);
            console.log(response.json());
            return response.json()
        })
        .subscribe((items: Person[]) => {
            console.log('items: ' + items);
            this.people = items;
        }, error => console.log(error))
}
}
```

Here if my try to get the json file (http://10.20.1.2:3000/data.json) as shown, Im able to get the json response.

What i need is i need to pass the API endpoint of the Magento 2 like this:

> http://10.20.1.2/Magento2/index.php/rest/V1/customers/1

The above rest endpoint works perfect if i call from Postman client.

If i use the same URL(http://10.20.1.2/Magento2/index.php/rest/V1/customers/1) in app.component.ts file i get:

[image]

If I use the URl with port 3000 as:(http://10.20.1.2:3000/Magento2/index.php/rest/V1/customers/1)   I get:

> Response {_body: "Cannot GET /Mage_ang2/index.php/rest/V1/customers/1↵", status: 404, statusText: "Ok", headers: Headers, type: 2…

Which part am i missing?

Comment: Did you set headers Access-Control-Allow-Origin?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set headers:

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: 'your_angular_server_address'

and

> Access-Control-Allow-Headers: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

It is [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) problem.

Comment: TL;DR The Magento server doesn't allow other server to make calls. You need to configure the Access-Control-Allow-Headers to solve this issue.

Comment: Could you please tell where i need to set the headers .? is it in my Rest API url?

Comment: You need to set headers to your REST API response here is exmaple for magento: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92105/magento-2-sending-a-custom-header-response-from-a-controller
and there: https://www.kathirvel.com/magento-returning-json-for-ajax-and-api-calls-response-from-controller-action/

Comment: After some workaround one suggested way of setting was like this Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" in .htaccess file of magento..after which im getting Response {_body: "Cannot GET /magento2/index.php/rest/V1/customers/1↵", status: 404, statusText: "Ok", headers: Headers, type: 2…

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the headers:

```
  /**
  * Interceptor set the headers for the request.
  * Params:
  *   - objectToSetHeadersTo: Request or Arguments that will contain the headers.
  **/
  private setHeaders(objectToSetHeadersTo: Request | RequestOptionsArgs) {
    const headers = objectToSetHeadersTo.headers;
    headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    if (this.token) {
      headers.set('Authorization', 'Token ' + this.token);
    }
  }
```